# I am not getting some tags inside the original html through file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

Below is my query:

```
$url = "https://www.hotels.com/search.do?resolved-location=CITY%3A1505671%3AUNKNOWN%3AUNKNOWN&destination-id=1505671&q-destination=Shreveport,%20Louisiana,%20United%20States%20of%20America&q-check-in=2017-07-09&q-check-out=2017-07-10&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0";


echo $html = file_get_contents($url);
```

This is retrieving the entire HTML page, but some html elements are missing in the content. However, I can see them in the browser source code. Also I downloaded the file and checked that those elements are there in the HTML content.

```
<p class="p-adr" dir="ltr"><span class="p-street-address">711 Horseshoe Blvd</span><span class="p-locality">, Bossier City</span><span class="p-region">, LA</span><span class="p-postal-code">, 71111</span><span class="p-country-name"> United States</span></p>
","
<p class="p-tel" dir="ltr">+65-6823-2329 (Singapore local number)</p>
```

Above is a piece of my HTML content and `file_get_contents` output is not rendering this piece of HTML `"," <p class="p-tel" dir="ltr">+65-6823-2329 (Singapore local number)</p>.`

I am not sure if it is because of  "," inside the HTML content and it breaks the format.

Comment: Are hotels.com cool with you scraping their content?

Comment: I hope so I am not sure :) :o This is just a client requirement.